# Rails 6.1.4 Deprecation warning: Rendering actions with '.'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I'm receiving a deprecation warning when running `rails test`. That warning being below. Any help is appreciated in identifying what I'm doing incorrectly.

(Edit: Side note, the render MUST break and return from the current controller call. I attempted to use `ApplicationController.render(...)` in place of the current `render` call, but that did not return from the controller call and I was receiving errors/warnings of `:no_content rendered`.)

Warning:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Rendering actions with '.' in the name is deprecated: actions/action_success.json (called from update at /<path>/app/controllers/table_base_controller.rb:39)
```

The code throwing the warning is specifically this call to `render` within a controller:

```
render('/actions/action_success.json', locals: {
  view: action.lookup_view('default'),
  action: action,
  area: current_area,
  account: current_account
})
```

I've tried taking off the `.json` as directed (also tried adding `template: <path>`, tried `file: <path>`), however, I receive this error in the test console:

```
Error:
TableControllerTest#test_Admin_should_update_via_loan_table:
ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template actions/action_success with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/<path>/app/views"

    app/controllers/table_base_controller.rb:39:in `update'
    app/controllers/application_controller.rb:79:in `with_account'
    test/controllers/table_controller_test.rb:14:in `block in <class:TableControllerTest>'
```

The file in question (path: `app/views/actions/action_success.json.jbuilder`):

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

json.status 'success'
json.status_code 200
json.messages action.messages

if view
  json.result do
    json.partial! view.to_s, result: action.result, locals: { area: area }
  end
else
  json.result action.result
end
```

Comment: Your request hitting the action isn't requesting a json response so it's attempting to render HTML

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Deprecating partial names that include a `.` was done to [prevent ambiguity in parsing the partial name](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/39164). We should explicitly state formats instead of including them in the partial name we pass to render.

Without the format in the string you pass in, you need to ensure the `formats` the render is expecting includes the format you're using, in this case `json`, which is not one of the default formats.

You can send it in as an option (and make the partial name an option as well) like this:

```rb
render(
  partial: '/actions/action_success',
  formats: [:json],
  locals: {
    view: action.lookup_view('default'),
    action: action,
    area: current_area,
    account: current_account
  }
)
```